# Why does C++ give me this error? How to say if an array of ints is either odd or even?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

This is supposed to be a code for user entering integers in an array and then calling a function that shows if they are even or odd. It then counts how many are even or odd (which I didn't get to yet because I am stuck here and I keep getting this error).

> invalid operands of types 'int [20]' and 'int' to binary 'operator%'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void getValue(int[], int);//function prototype

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;
    int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];

    cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(1);

    //get ints from user
    getValue(numbers, ARRAY_SIZE);

     if ( numbers % 2== 0 )
        // if the integer when divided by 2 has no remainder then it's even.
        cout << numbers << " is even "<<endl;
    else
        // the integer is odd
        cout << numbers << " is odd "<<endl;

    return 0;
}

void getValue(int numbers[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
    //loop counter
    int index;

    //get each value
    for(index = 0; index <= ARRAY_SIZE - 1; index++)
    {
        cout<< "Enter an integer " << (index + 1)<< " : ";
        cin>> numbers[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: So if the user provides "3 4 5", what should the program print?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

First, this is illegal in C++:

```
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;
int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

You need to declare

```
int numbers[20];
```

instead.

Second,

```
if ( numbers % 2== 0 )
```

numbers is an array of 20 values.  What exactly is it meant to be using the % operator on?  You probably want a loop that will check each int in the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
  if ( numbers[i] % 2== 0 )
    ...
  else
    ...
}
```

Comment: ok yes i see that now! I had it like that because i thought it had to be blank because of user input- and thanks i understand

Comment: `const int ARRAY_SIZE = 20; int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];` is legal (try compiling it you wont get an error), As its declared `const` its permitted to be used to initialize a static array.

Comment: `const int ARRAY_SIZE = 20; int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];` would be illegal in C. It is perfectly legal in C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void getValue(int [], int);//function prototype

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;
    int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);

    //get ints from user
    getValue(numbers, ARRAY_SIZE);

    //I added this FOR loop.
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE - 1; i++)
    {
        //I also added the [i] so that the number is outputted as well
        if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0)

            // if the integer when divided by 2 has no remainder then it's even.

            // and here as well
            cout << numbers[i] << " is even "
            << endl;
        else

            // the integer is odd

            cout << numbers[i] << " is odd "
            << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}

void getValue(int numbers[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
    //loop counter
    int index;

    //get each value
    for (index = 0; index <= ARRAY_SIZE - 1; index++)
    {
        cout << "Enter an integer " << (index + 1) << " : ";
        cin >> numbers[index];
    }
}
```

I added a for loop and the array brackets on the output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your array, just add a loop and check if (numbers[index] % 2 == 0)
Above answers should give you right results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a range for loop for fixed-size arrays:

```
for (int value : numbers)
{
    if (value % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << value << " is even.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << value << " is odd.\n";
    }
}
```